# How to open all instances of same application on Windows 11?

Tags: windows, taskbar, windows-11, multiple-instances

I often have multiple instances of an application(e.g terminal windows) minimized on Windows 11.

What's the best way to open all of them at the same time(via either shortcut or minimum clicks)? Ctrl+clicking the application icon on taskbar seems to be the only currently.

I heard that `Shift + Right-click` on the taskbar icon and selecting "Restore all windows" used to work but that doesn't seem to do anything useful on Windows 11.

**Update1:**
To add some info, I want to replicate the behavior that we see on macOS i.e, when you click an icon on dock, all its instance windows show up on screen. E.g, if there's 7 iTerm windows minimized, clicking on the iTerm icon on the dock, all of them show up.

Comment: Once you open all your instances, there is always one more to open. So I do not think Windows knows and most likely, natively, you cannot do this.

Comment: Maybe you could use a virtual desktop?

Comment: Are you looking for unminimizing all instances of a process? (Add to your comment `@harrymc` for me to be notified.)

Comment: @harrymc Sure. That works out.

Comment: @zomega Multiple desktops switching are not what I am looking for. I need my work on same view.

Comment: @Anutrix You could write your own tool using cygwin. It's not that hard maybe 50 lines of code.

Comment: @zomega I don't use Cygwin. Also, I am avoiding writing my own tool as I would need to modify Window 11's native behavior on clicking it's taskbar icons. An OS option(or a very simple tool), if it exists is what I am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Install [AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/). It is very well [documented](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v2/).

Solution. Create a new AutoHotkey file with .ahk extension and add code:

```
GroupAdd, cmd, ahk_exe cmd.exe
Loop, 10
{
    GroupActivate, cmd
}
```

1. GroupAdd creates a program group based on window title, class or process name. All 3 can be included. The processes don't have to be the same to be added to the group.
2. 1st GroupAdd argument -> **`cmd`**, is the name of the group, it can be whatever you want it, like ex. **`Terminals`** or **`CommandWindows`**.
3. 2nd GroupAdd argument **`ahk_exe cmd.exe`** targets specific process, it can also be used like this: "**`WindowTitle ahk_class ConsoleWindowClass ahk_exe cmd.exe`**"
4. The **`Loop`** with parameter 10 loops through all 10 windows.
5. **`GroupActivate`** using the loop activates (restores) the group, all 10 minimized windows.
6. Sometimes the loop doesn't activate (restores) all windows, so just add a higher number, like 20.

If you need to activate windows with specified titles, then you can do this:

```
WinActivate, Title1 ahk_exe cmd.exe
WinActivate, Title2 ahk_exe cmd.exe
WinActivate, Title3 ahk_exe cmd.exe
```

etc.

Just change **`Title#`** to your needs.